# How to Query PriceBookEntry to Opportunity Products to PriceBook

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

Can anyone help to query the **pricebookEntry** to **opportunity product**
and the **price book** to **pricebookEntry**
I have to get the particular id of the price book which is from the
opportunity product->PriceBookEntry->Pricebook id

```
if(trigger.isBefore)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLI=[SELECT PricebookEntryId,Quantity,UnitPrice,Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem];
    List<PricebookEntry> PE =[SELECT Pricebook2Id FROM PricebookEntry];
    List<Pricebook2> PB=[SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Price_Book__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c,Price__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r)FROM Pricebook2];
    List<Product2> PR=[SELECT Id,(SELECT Product__c,Price_Book__c,Price__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c FROM Tier_Pricings__r)FROM Product2];
    List<Tier_Price__c> TP=[SELECT Product__c,Price_Book__c,Price__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c FROM Tier_Price__c];

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
    { 
        for(OpportunityLineItem PItem : trigger.new)
        {
            for(PriceBookEntry l: PItem.PricebookEntry)
            {
                    Decimal prdPrice;
                for(Pricebook2 d:l)
                {
                    for(Tier_Price__c c : d.Tier_Pricings__r)
                    {
                        prdPrice = c.Price__c;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }   
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a trigger on `OpportunityLineItem`, by definition, every `OpportunityLineItem` will use the same `Pricebook2Id` as its parent `Opportunity`

So, the essence of your trigger needs to simply be:

```
   ...   
   Set<Id> oppoIds = new Set<Id>();
   for (OpportunityLineItem oli: Trigger.new) { // Pass 1: get all parent OppoIds
       oppoIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
   }

   Map<Id,Opportunity> opposById = new Map<Id,Opportunity) ( // get parent Oppos
     [SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: oppoIds]);

   for (OpportunityLineItem oli: Trigger.new) { // Pass 2: get OLI's Pricebook2Id
     // Get OLI's pricebook2Id  
     Id pricebook2Id = opposById.get(oli.OpportunityId).Pricebook2Id;
   }
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks Cropredy

Comment: I have another doubt i have to take custom object from the pricebookId                               List<Pricebook2> PBTierPrices = new List<Pricebook2>();
Map<Id,Pricebook2> PricesById = new Map<Id,Pricebook2> 
 ([SELECT Id,Name, (SELECT Id,Price_Book__c,To_Unit__c,From_Unit__c,Price__c FROM Tier_Prices__r)FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Id IN : PBTierPrices]);
  for (Pricebook2 Pricebk: Trigger.new) {Id pricebook2Id PricesById.get(Pricebk.Id).Pricebook2Id;}

Comment: IS this correct,I got error while saving the IN PBtier prices

Comment: `PBTierPrices` is an empty list in the above snippet. I suggest if you are having issues, and given I answered your specific question, that you post a NEW question with a clear statement of your issue and the code you are having trouble with